Where can I find Stefan Wewers' doctoral thesis "Construction of Hurwitz Spaces"?
I am looking for a copy of Stefan Wewers' doctoral thesis titled "Construction of Hurwitz Spaces," which was defended at the University of Essen in 1998. I have tried searching through various online academic databases but have not been successful. Does anyone know where I can find a digital version of this thesis? Any guidance on how to access it would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe ask the author? An internet search will reveal his current address.

https://www.uni-ulm.de/en/mawi/institute-of-algebra-and-number-theory/institute-members/prof-dr-stefan-wewers/

I've already looked on the personal website and haven't found it. I'm waiting for a response from the author at the moment.

Could you contact the library of the University of Duisburg-Essen for a copy? It seems to be held there as a 79 page preprint of the Institut für Experimentelle Mathematik.
